# IndentationError while plotting the Gauge

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, data-visualization

Could anyone please explain why the following code is throwing IndentationError.

I am trying to plot a gauge with sort of real time values. This code was running fine earlier, now when I restarted my system, the same code is throwing an error. Please explain the error.

```
%matplotlib inline
import os, sys
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, Wedge, Rectangle


def degree_range(n): 
    start = np.linspace(0,180,n+1, endpoint=True)[0:-1]
    end = np.linspace(0,180,n+1, endpoint=True)[1::]
    mid_points = start + ((end-start)/2.)
    yield np.c_[start, end], mid_points
def rot_text(ang): 
    rotation = np.degrees(np.radians(ang) * np.pi / np.pi - np.radians(90))
    yield rotation

def gauge(labels=['LOW','MEDIUM','HIGH','VERY HIGH','EXTREME'], 
          colors='jet_r', arrow=1, title='', fname=False): 
    """
    some sanity checks first

    """
    N = len(labels)
    if arrow > N: 
        raise Exception("\n\nThe category ({}) is greated than \
        the length\nof the labels ({})".format(arrow, N))
    """
    if colors is a string, we assume it's a matplotlib colormap
    and we discretize in N discrete colors 
    """
    if isinstance(colors, str):
        cmap = cm.get_cmap(colors, N)
        cmap = cmap(np.arange(N))
        colors = cmap[::-1,:].tolist()
    if isinstance(colors, list): 
        if len(colors) == N:
            colors = colors[::-1]
        else: 
            raise Exception("\n\nnumber of colors {} not equal \
            to number of categories{}\n".format(len(colors), N))
    """
    begins the plotting
    """

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    ang_range, mid_points = degree_range(N)

    labels = labels[::-1]

    """
    plots the sectors and the arcs
    """
    patches = []
    for ang, c in zip(ang_range, colors): 
        # sectors
        patches.append(Wedge((0.,0.), .4, *ang, facecolor='w', lw=2))
        # arcs
        patches.append(Wedge((0.,0.), .4, *ang, width=0.10, facecolor=c, lw=2, alpha=0.5))

    [ax.add_patch(p) for p in patches]


    """
    set the labels (e.g. 'LOW','MEDIUM',...)
    """

    for mid, lab in zip(mid_points, labels): 

        ax.text(0.35 * np.cos(np.radians(mid)), 0.35 * np.sin(np.radians(mid)), lab, \
            horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center', fontsize=14, \
            fontweight='bold', rotation = rot_text(mid))

    """
    set the bottom banner and the title
    """
    r = Rectangle((-0.4,-0.1),0.8,0.1, facecolor='w', lw=2)
    ax.add_patch(r)

    ax.text(0, -0.05, title, horizontalalignment='center', \
         verticalalignment='center', fontsize=22, fontweight='bold')

    """
    plots the arrow now
    """

    pos = mid_points[abs(arrow - N)]

    ax.arrow(0, 0, 0.225 * np.cos(np.radians(pos)), 0.225 * np.sin(np.radians(pos)), \
                 width=0.04, head_width=0.09, head_length=0.1, fc='k', ec='k')

    ax.add_patch(Circle((0, 0), radius=0.02, facecolor='k'))
    ax.add_patch(Circle((0, 0), radius=0.01, facecolor='w', zorder=11))

    """
    removes frame and ticks, and makes axis equal and tight
    """

    ax.set_frame_on(False)
    ax.axes.set_xticks([])
    ax.axes.set_yticks([])
    ax.axis('equal')
    plt.tight_layout()
    if fname:
        fig.savefig(fname, dpi=200)

       gauge(labels=['LOW','MEDIUM','HIGH'], \
      colors=['r','y','g'], arrow=2, title='something here')
```

Please help and explain what mistake I am making?
I have checked the identation many times still I am not able to figure the error.

The actual error is:

```
> File "<tokenize>", line 91
>     gauge(labels=['LOW','MEDIUM','HIGH'], \
>     ^ IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: The last three lines of your code all have different indentation. Do you know how block syntax in Python works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's saying that your indentation is not consistent. The problem area is here:

```
if fname:
        fig.savefig(fname, dpi=200)

       gauge(labels=['LOW','MEDIUM','HIGH'], \
       ^
      colors=['r','y','g'], arrow=2, title='something here')
```

Can you see how the line starting with `gauge` is one space *behind* the line starting with `fig`? They do not line up, and Python is telling you this. That is definitely an issue, and the line where you continue the `gauge(labels=...` statement(starting with `colors` could also be a problem because it is not lined up with the `fig` line either.
To fix this problem, change your code like this:

```
if fname:
        fig.savefig(fname, dpi=200)
        gauge(labels=['LOW','MEDIUM','HIGH'], colors=['r','y','g'], arrow=2, title='something here') 
        # now everything lines up just fine.
```